# Validation_data argument in sklearn fit method

Tags: python, validation, scikit-learn

I am trying to get a separate predefined validation set passed to sklearn fit method. I was wondering if there is already a given way in the sklearn API to fulfill this need, like it is given within the keras API:

```
model.fit(train_X, train_y, validation_data=(val_x, val_y))
```

and

```
model.fit(train_X, train_y, validation_split=0.3)
```

Is there an equivialent within the sklearn API for the argument `validation_data=(x_val, y_val)`? I only can find the `validation_split` argument within the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to the docs [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html), no, you cannot, but you can use the `score` method after training on the validation set - in this case `val_x` and `val_y` - to see the performance of the model